# Wp redirection doesn't not change url in browser

Tags: actions, wp-redirect

I'm writing a WatuPro plugin customization. I need to redirect users to specific url when an exam is completed. I have to do it by code because i need to attach some dynamic get parameters to the request.
To intercept an exam completion i have the action :

```
watupro_completed_exam
```

i this action i'm trying to achive the redirection:

```
 $complete_url="http://localhost/mysite/resultpage?email=".$email."&param_1=".$param_1;

 wp_redirect( $complete_url );
```

the redirect works, because i see "resultpage content" but the url in the browser not change, it remains the same.

So my question is not related to Watu Pro plugin, it is a general question:
In which case wp_redirect can change content of the page without change the url ?

This is my .htaccess

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /mysite/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /mysite/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Comment: redirections can only happen _before_ any HTML output occurs, and should be followed by an `exit;` statement. Unfortunately there's no information about where and when your code is running, or where the variables used to construct the URL come from. Additionally you can't ask questions about 3rd party plugins here as they're offtopic and not in this stacks scope, you should ask in a WatuPro user community/group or their official support routes for help working with that plugin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> In which case wp_redirect can change content of the page without change the url ?

No, if used correctly there are no situations where `wp_redirect` interferes with the content of a page. It's job is to do a HTTP redirect telling the browser to stop and start a new fresh request using a new URL, and that is its **only** job. Your HTAccess is not a factor in this. If the URL did not change then there was no redirect.

I suspect that you've either called the function in the middle of a page when it is too late to redirect, and that you also did not `exit;` after calling it like the documented examples show, and it's very likely that your PHP error log is full of warnings and errors about "headers have already been sent".

### How To Redirect

To use `wp_redirect`, it must be called *before* any output is sent. The moment something is sent to the browser, be that whitespace or the opening HTML tag, all opportunities to use `wp_redirect` have ended. *This means you can never use it in a shortcode widget or block.*

If you want to use it, it must be done on a hook, and one that runs *before* the template is loaded. It must also have an `exit` statement immediately after it.

Note that when I say HTML, I mean *any* HTML, not just post HTML, but headers, meta tags, `<head>` or even blank spaces. From the moment of the first `echo` or `?>` PHP will send out HTTP headers telling the browser to expect HTML and your chance to redirect has gone and cannot be recovered. The only way to redirect at that point is to do it in javascript or HTML.

#### Which Hook?

Which hook you should use depends on how the plugin you're working with is built. There are a number of generic hooks that might work such as `init`/`after_theme_setup` but this cannot be done from a theme template or once HTML has been sent to the browser.

Your question states that you're trying to use `watupro_completed_exam`, you would need to ask their support or read the plugins code to identify when this hook fires to see if it can be used for this.

**This means what you want may not be fixable without the help of WatuPro because only they can change when the `watupro_completed_exam` hook fires, which may not be possible to do, and there is no generic WordPress fix for this specific use case.**

Comment: I found the WatuPro codebase and saw that the action you're using is called from a shortcode, meaning it can _never_ be used with `wp_redirect` because it is too late to use a HTTP redirect. You would need to use an earlier hook such as `init` then write code to detect that an exam has finished in order to perform a HTTP redirect. Fixing this in the Watu Pro plugin would require significant effort and refactoring they're unlikely to do, you should ask anyway as they might be able to build new hooks for this. Eitherway this is a Watu Pro specific question, no general WP answer is possible